# Is there a way to simulate integer bitwise operations for _m256 types on AVX?

Tags: c++, c, integer, sse, avx

I have a boolean expression that I have managed to implement in SSE2. Now I would have liked to try implementing it in AVX exploiting an additional factor 2 in parallelism increase (from 128 bit SIMD type to 256). However, AVX does not support integer operation (which AVX2 does, but I am working on a Sandy Bridge processor so it is not an option currently). However, since there are [AVX intrinsics for bitwise operations](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_bk_bitwiseops.htm). I figured I could make a try by just converting my integer types to float types and see if it works.

First test was a success:

```
__m256 ones = _mm256_set_ps(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
__m256 twos = _mm256_set_ps(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2); 
__m256 result = _mm256_and_ps(ones, twos);
```

I'm guetting all 0's as I am supposed to. Simularly AND'ing the twos instead I get a result of 2. But when trying 11 XOR 4 accordingly:

```
__m256 elevens = _mm256_set_ps(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11); 
__m256 fours = _mm256_set_ps(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4); 
__m256 result2 = _mm256_xor_ps(elevens, fours);
```

The result is 6.46e-46 (i.e. close to 0) and not 15. Simularly doing 11 OR 4 gives me a value of 22 and not 15 as it should be. I don't understand why this is. Is it a bug or some configuration I am missing?

I was actually expecting my hypothesis of working with float as if they were integers to not work since the integer initialized to a float value might not actually be the precise value but a close approximation. But even then, I am surprised by the result I get.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem or must I upgrade my CPU to get AVX2 support enable this?

Comment: It sounds like you're printing an integer as a float to get 6.46e-46.  Are you sure your `printf()` formatting specifiers are correct?

Comment: I was not printing. I just checked the value in the the Visual  Studio debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first test worked by accident.

1 as a float is 0x3f800000, 2 is 0x40000000. In general, it wouldn't work that way.

But you can absolutely do it, you just have to make sure that you're working with the right bit-pattern. Don't convert your integers to floats - reinterpret-cast them. That corresponds to intrinsics such as `_mm256_castsi256_ps`, or storing your ints to memory and reading them as floats (that won't change them, in general only math operations care about what the floats *mean*, the rest work with the raw bit patterns, check the list of exceptions that an instruction can make to make sure).

Comment: Aha. Thanks. That makes sense. I give it a try and mark your answer as correct if it works.

Comment: @Toby999 But be aware that on all current Intel processors, the floating-point versions of the bitwise logic instructions have only 1/3 the throughput as the integer versions. So if you're doing this for performance, you might want to think twice. It might even backfire unless you're limited by decoder bandwidth.

Comment: On Sandy and Ivy Bridge, integer SSE bitwise logic can go to any of ports 0, 1, or 5 at one/cycle. That's 3 per cycle. But floating-point SSE bitwise logic can only go to port 5 at one/cycle. So it's limited to 1 per cycle. On Haswell, it's the same, but it has AVX2  - which makes the point moot.

Comment: You can use the the AVX integer load and store operations (e.g. `_mm256_loadu_si256`) with AVX you just can't do the integer operations (e.g. `_mm256_add_epi32`) with AVX.  So you should be able to load in the integergs and then use `_mm256_and_ps`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input.  After having successfully implemented an initial version of the full math expression indeed, the AVX version has less throughput than the SSE2 version. I guess it due to your explanation Mystical. I wasn't expecting much extra anyways since I am quite closer to the memory read max bandwidth anyways I think. Disappointing though. ;(

Answer (score 5):

You don't need AVX2 to use the AVX integer load and store operations: see the [intel intrinsic guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide).  So you can load your integers using AVX, reinterpret-cast to float, use float bitwise operations, and then reinterpret-cast back to int.  The reinterpret-casts don't generate any instructions, they just make the compiler happy.  Try this:

```
//compiled and ran on an Ivy Bridge system with AVX but without AVX2
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
int main() {
    int a[8] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14};
    int b[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1};
    int c[8];

    __m256i a8 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)a);
    __m256i b8 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)b);
    __m256i c8 = _mm256_castps_si256(
        _mm256_or_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(a8), _mm256_castsi256_ps(b8)));
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)c, c8);
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d ", c[i]); printf("\n");
    //output: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
}
```

Of course, as Mystical pointed out this might not be worth doing but that does not mean you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was helpful since it is time consuming digging out the correct intrinsics methods.

Comment: there are options for aligning variables so you don't need to deal with unaligned loads

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I was working with the assumption that it does not matter any more. The throughput and latency of the aligned and unaligned load/store instructions is the same on aligned memory. That's the theory. But in practice I'm still seeing a difference so I agree with you that the aligned load instructions should be used.